# xpath select referenced xml node

Tags: select, xpath

I need to select a node whose "name" attribute is equal to the current node's "references" attribute.

```
<node name="foo" />
<node name="bar" references="foo" />
```

I couldn't find a way to express this in XPATH. Any ideas. Ive tried the following:

```
./node[@name=@references]
./node[@name={@references}]
```

Obviously the above didn't work. I guess the real problem is in the brackets; how do I signify which attribute comes from which node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're attempting isn't possible with pure XPath.  Whenever you start a new predicate (the part surrounded by brackets), the context changes to the node that started the predicate.  That means that you can't directly compare attributes from two separate elements in a single predicate without storing one in a variable.

What language are you using?  You will have to store the value of the "name" attribute from the first node in a variable.

For example, in XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="name" select="/node[1]/@name" />
<xsl:value-of select="/node[@references = $name]" />
```

In XQuery

```
let $name := /node[1]/@name
return /node[@references = $name]
```

Comment: Wouldn't this work? `/node[@references=current()/@name]`  (I know the question is a little old, but I used to use the variable trick a lot, so thought this might be helpful.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want. This gives you any node which has references from any node to it:

```
//node[@name=//node/@references]
```

Comment: True, I hadn't thought of that, if this is what you are going for.

Comment: This is extremely inefficient because of the nested `"//"` operator and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

The natural solution:

```
node[@name = current()/@references]
```

This works in XSLT, since you speak of "current node", which I translate as "the XSLT context node". No need for an extra variable.